# Iterar objeto de varios niveles

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto de 3 niveles con un codigo que itera por cada nivel, si en caso los niveles incrementan quisiera mejorarlo para que sea mas dinamico, se puede usar recursividad, o aunque sea no recursividad pero como se podria optimizar?

```js
var obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
    "level1": {
      first: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    "level2": {
      first: "juan",
      last: "perez"
    }
  }
}]


obj.forEach(function(item) {

  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    let value = item[key];
    
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key2) {
       console.log(value[key2].first, value[key2].last);
     
    });
  });
});
```

El resultado deberia ser: `seccion1 level1 john doe level2 juan perez`

Comment: Pero que es lo que deseas que devuelva? Un Objeto? Un JSON? Que estructura?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera listo edite mi pregunta, revisalo porfavor, solo quiero mostrar

Comment: sep.. recursividad se usan para estos casos...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debes hacer una funcion recursiva, evitas repetir codigo:

```js
var obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
    "level1": {
      first: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    "level2": {
      first: "juan",
      last: "perez"
    }
  }
}]

function iterarObjeto(objeto){
  Object.keys(objeto).forEach(function(key) {
  
    if(typeof(objeto[key]) === "object"){
     console.info(`objeto ${key} vamos a iterar!`);
     iterarObjeto(objeto[key])
    }else{
      console.log(objeto[key])
    }

  });
}
obj.forEach(function(item) {
  iterarObjeto(item)

});
```

Podemos evitar la ultima iteracion, pero necesitas saber la ultima iteracion , te evitas recorrer de nuevo el objeto, el ejemplo a continuación:

```js
const obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
    "level1": { first: "John", last: "Doe"  } ,
    "level2": { first: "juan", last: "perez"}
  }
}]
const ultimaIteracion = 2

function iterarObjeto(objeto, numeroIteracion){
  if (numeroIteracion == ultimaIteracion){
    console.log(objeto);
    return;
  }
  Object.keys(objeto).forEach(function(key) {
  
    if(typeof(objeto[key]) === "object"){
     console.info(`objeto ${key} vamos a iterar!`);
     iterarObjeto(objeto[key], numeroIteracion + 1)
    }

  });
}
obj.forEach(function(item) {
  iterarObjeto(item, 0)

});
```

Answer (score 7):

Usando la estrategia de *divide y vencerás*: Un objeto de este tipo puede tener como propiedades un tipo primitivo (string, number, bigint, null, undefined...) u otro objeto anidado.

```js
let obj = {
  a : 'primitivo',
  b : 0,
  c : null,
  d : {}, //objeto vacío
  e: [] //objeto array
};


function tipos(o) {
  for (let key in o) {
    console.log('La propiedad ', key,' es ',typeof o[key]);
  }
}

tipos(obj);
```

Por tanto tienes un caso base: la propiedad es un primitivo.
El caso recursivo es cuando la propiedad del objeto es otro objeto:

```js
var obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
    "level1": {
      first: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    "level2": {
      first: "juan",
      last: "perez"
    }
  }
}]

function printObject(o) {
  let text = '';
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof o[key] === 'object') {
      // objeto: mostramos la clave y hacemos una llamada recursiva
      text += `${key} ${printObject(o[key])}`; 
    } else {
      text += `${o[key]} `; //primitivo: directamente imprimimos el valor
    }
  });
  return text;
}

console.log(printObject(obj));
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta, aunque creo que se puede optimizar un poco mas.

Answer (score 4):

Acotando a la respuesta de Pablo Lozano, se pueden reducir un par de lineas de código cambiando el `if` por condicionales `?` y `:` e inicializando la variable `text` al declarar la función, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```js
var obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
    "level1": {
      first: "John",
      last: "Doe"
    },
    "level2": {
      first: "juan",
      last: "perez"
    }
  }
}]

function printObject(o,text = '') {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    typeof o[key] === 'object' ? text += `${key} ${printObject(o[key])}` : text += `${o[key]} ` 
  });
  return text;
}

console.log(printObject(obj));
```

Y así quedaría la forma de iterar un objeto de varios niveles mas optima posible, saludos.

Comment: A mi gusto se pierde legibilidad y el rendimiento será el mismo. Es ya cuestión de gustos escribir de un modo u otro

Comment: @PabloLozano es cierto, pero compactar código ayuda a crear programas de menor peso y disminuir el consumo de datos.

Answer (score 2):

te muestro dos alternativas que puede optimizar a criterio para obtener el resultado que pides.

```js
var obj = [{
  "seccion1": {
   "level1": {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
   },
   "level2": {
    first: "juan",
    last: "perez"
   }
  }
 }];
 console.log('Opcion 1');
    //opcion 1
    obj.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
   let value = item[key];
   Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key2) {
    console.log(key+ ' ' + key2 + ' ' + value[key2].first + ' ' + value[key2].last);
   });
  });
    });
 console.log('Opcion 2');
 //opcion 2
 obj.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
   let value = item[key];
   let res = key;
   Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key2) {
    res = res + ' ' + key2 + ' ' + value[key2].first + ' ' + value[key2].last;
   });
   console.log(res);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Y si tiene mas niveles como hace con estas funciones?