# ¿Como puedo recorrer el siguiente arreglo?

Tags: php, array, php7, foreach

Hola tengo el siguiente arreglo de arreglo.

```
    Array
    (
        [myPets] => GASTON
        [pet_id] => 31
        [service_id] => 1
        [start_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2022-02-10T08:00:00
                [1] => 2022-02-10T08:00:00
                [2] => 2022-02-10T08:00:00
            )
    
        [end_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2022-02-10T18:00:00
                [1] => 2022-02-10T18:00:00
                [2] => 2022-02-10T18:00:00
            )
    
        [confirmed] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
            )
    
    )
```

¿Cómo podría recorrerlo?

Se que puedo utilizar foreach para ello, claro esta utilizo php7 con el framewok cakephp en su version 3.8

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida de forma correcta en otro post, te recomiendo que pases por [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280964/iterar-objeto-de-varios-niveles) para que veas la respuesta a tú problema.

Comment: @AlbertoMarun eso es javascript, su array es php

Comment: No hay tag, no es evidente en qué lenguaje lo quiere hacer. Hay que [edit] la pregunta y añadir el código relevante y la etiqueta del lenguaje deseado

Comment: Bueno, no voy a discutir por eso, calm down! :-)   (pero que nos apostamos?)

Comment: jajaja dale, una cerveza? :P

Comment: jeje, bueno, venga, que no sea dicho, aunque sea virtual,.... ya veras ya :-)

Comment: Es correcto, los unicos TAG son array y foreach, por favor, lean antes de escribir, Gracias @Alfabravo

Comment: Por favor, pasen por caja :-D... a ver, es que estoy muy acostumbrado a ver esa sintaxis en el print_r de php. no lo decia por decir... en cambio en javascript no

Comment: Actualice publicación y Tag, gracias por notificar que faltaban

Comment: Listo, ahora soy yo el que pago la cerveza

Comment: Venga, va, os perdono la cerveza, me quedo con el gusto de haber tenido la razón :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que estás hablando de PHP (como dicen en los comentarios), se trataría de hacer lo siguiente:

```php
foreach ($array_valores as $key => $value) {
  /* En key tienes la clave y el $value el valor */
  if (!is_array($value)) {
    echo "El valor de $key es $value";
  }
  else {
    echo "El valor de $key es un array";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrerlos con un doble bucle anidado (el primero sobre el array original y el segundo sobre sus elementos que tambien sean array). El tipo de bucle da igual, puede ser `foreach()`, `for()`, otros (imagino que hay mas :-)).

O bien acceder a ellos directamente mediante esta sintaxis:

```php
echo $array['start_date'][0];  // te devolverá su valor, es decir 2022-02-10T08:00:00
```

o bien

```php
$array['start_date'][0] = "2022-02-10T10:22:12";  // establecerá su valor de nuevo
```