# tengo un objeto con una propiedad que es ingrediente1, ingrediente2, ingrediente3,.... hasta 15. como puedo iterar?

Tags: java

necesito la alternativa a ir mirando dada.strIngredient1,dada.strIngredient1,dada.strIngredient2,dada.strIngredient3,dada.strIngredient4,dada.strIngredient5......,
este es el codigo que no me funciona:

```
function carregaIngredients(dada) {
    let item;
    for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        item = 'strIngredient' + i;
        
        if (dada.item) {
//hacer lo que sea con el
        }
    }
}
```

dada es un objeto, y strIngredient1, stingredient2... son propiedades de él

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280964/iterar-objeto-de-varios-niveles)

Comment: ` Object.entries(data).forEach(([keyName, keyValue])=>{
   //hacer lo que sea con data[keyName] o keyValue
})`

Comment: es en java que pregunto